# Export pads as a pdf file in Altium

Tags: soldering, altium, stencil

I'm not used to working on Altium Designer(17.1). I couldnt find how can I export only pad layouts to making a stencil schematic. 
It is good to export as a pdf file if it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a PcbDoc go to File -> Fabrication Outputs -> Final

There you get a print view of all layers. You can select the ones you want and print to pdf. Make sure you have the scaling you want.

In the configuration you can select for each page the layers you want to see. By selecting "Create Mask Set" you get the Paste and Overlay layers only. Remove the Mechanical.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for detail answer. 
Unfortunately, It gives me wrong ratio. It has drawn all pads on the all over paper. I need the real ratio with my board to obtain real size stencil schematic.

Comment: Did you try this: 
Right click on the small preview and select Page Setup. Now in the Scaling properties set to "Scaled Print" with Scale 1

Comment: Scaled print did what i want.